# Cohomology of function spaces

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

Let $M,N$ be smooth manifolds and $C^\infty(M,N)$ be the function space with Whitney topology.

If we know the cohomology groups of $M,N$, can we calculate the cohomology groups of $C^\infty(M,N)$?

Comment: The Federer spectral sequence computes the homotopy groups of the mapping space. Its 2nd page is the cohomology of $M$ with coefficients in the homotopy of $N$. I doubt that the cohomology of $M$ and $N$ alone can be used to study the cohomology of the mapping space.

Comment: I doubt such a thing is very doable in general. Even in the arguably simplest case $M=S^1$, this is a hard problem. The basic strategy is first to compute cohomology of the based loop space using the Serre spectral sequence, and then in turn the cohomology of the free loop space using the Serrre spectral sequence again. Another tactic there is to use Sullivan's rational homotopy theory, but I do not know too much about this.

Comment: Isn't $C^\infty(M,N)$ homotopy equivalent to the continous mapping space $\mathrm{Map}(M,N)$? And in that case, can't we use simplicial methods to get a grip on it?

Comment: Corollaries 7.4, 7.5, & 7.6 of http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1991-326-01/S0002-9947-1991-1010881-8/ seem to be relevant here.

Comment: Yes it is. And the Anderson spectral sequence uses those methods.

Comment: Not in general: there is a (co)homology equivalence $\Sigma \to S^3$ from the Poincar{\'e} 3-sphere, but applying $C^\infty(S^1, -) \simeq \mathrm{map}(S^1, -)$ gives spaces with different $H^0$'s.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems there exists such a thing: There is a spectral sequence by Anderson that computes the homology of the mapping space out of the cohomology of $M$ and the homology of $N$. Here is a link to the announcement:

http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1972-78-05/S0002-9904-1972-13034-9/S0002-9904-1972-13034-9.pdf

I have not been able to find the subsequent paper with the proof.